# push plist from UITableViewCell into UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, plist, pushviewcontroller

I have a plist that compiles a UITableView by the key "Title", the plist is below.The Table View populates correctly, I push a view controller with this:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath;
{
    LocationsReviewViewController *nextViewController = [[LocationsReviewViewController alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [[[tableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey: @"Rows"] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    nextViewController.title = [rowData objectForKey: @"Title"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: nextViewController animated: YES];
}
```

How do I get `nextViewController` above to retain some information about which object in the table was selected? In addition, how do I show the strings contained in each subtree key on the new `nextViewController` view? What should that ViewDidLoad look like?

Here's what it the ViewDidLoad currently looks like for the nextViewController (description is a UILabel). Why doesn't show @"3001 Sunset" when the "LA Place 1" row is selected:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data3" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSDictionary *subtree = [dictionary objectForKey: @"Subtree"];
    description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[subtree objectForKey:@"Item 2"]];
}

<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Rows</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Subtree</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Los Angeles, CA</string>
                    <string>Tuesday</string>
                    <string>3001 Sunset</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>LA Place 1</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Subtree</key>
                <array>
                    <string>New York, NY</string>
                    <string>Sunday</string>
                    <string>1400 Broadway</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>NYC Place 1</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Subtree</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Austin, TX</string>
                    <string>Sunday</string>
                    <string>2400 Lamar Blvd</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Austin Place 1</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Section1</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your Data3.plist I see it's a dictionary of 2 items.

- First item is NSArray with a key: Rows
- Second item is a NSString with a key: Title

So in your `- (void)viewDidLoad` your code is incorrect.  This should be the correct code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data3" ofType:@"plist"]];
    // get the Rows object
    NSArray *rows = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Rows"];
    // The array object contains 3 NSDictionary
    NSDictionary *firstItem = [rows objectAtIndex:0]; // I am just getting the first item
    // once I have the dictionary, which have 2 items, Subtree & title 
    NSArray *subtree = [firstItem objectForKey: @"Subtree"];
    // subtree object is NSArray with 3 NSString object, therefore you have to use index
    description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[subtree objectAtIndex:2]];
}
```

[image: Data3.plist screenshot]

Now, if you want to pass data to the next controller you should add a property to your `LocationsReviewViewController` object.

In your LocationsReviewViewController.h:

```
// declare an ivar
NSDictionary *data;

// declare property
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *data;
```

In your LocationsReviewViewController.m:

```
@synthesize data;
```

When you alloc the LocationsReviewViewController object:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
{
    NSDictionary *rowData = [[[tableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey: @"Rows"] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    LocationsReviewViewController *nextViewController = [[LocationsReviewViewController alloc]init];
    nextViewController.data = rowData;  // pass in your dictionary to your controller
    nextViewController.title = [rowData objectForKey: @"Title"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: nextViewController animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, I need the ViewDidLoad method to show the data that corresponds to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. I can't choose which objectAtIndex each time. The table from the DidSelect method has a list of Title's from the plist (LA Place 1) for example. Once that LA Place 1 row is selected, I need to show the other items (0-2) in the plise in the new 'nextViewController' view.

Comment: And I posted code/example where you can pass the data to the view controller.

Comment: I changed the NSDictionary *subtree = [firstItem objectForKey: @"Subtree"]; to NSArray *subtree, or else subtree wouldn't respond to object at index in the next line. I'm still getting (null) for description.text. Does *data need to be a part of the ViewDidLoad?

Comment: DId you add the data property I presented in my answer?

Comment: I think so, I run an NSLog after NSArray *rows = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Rows"]; and get (null) for *rows. Shouldn't it return the names of the three dictionaries then?

Comment: If you added the property and pass in the NSDictionary you don't need to load Data3.plist.

Comment: -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *array = [data objectForKey:@"Subtree"];
    description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:2]];
}

Comment: @Black Frog, I want to make Item 1 a section/group header, I can't seem to get the parameters right between mutable arrays and indexpath.section. Can you help me on this?